# Implementation of Huffman Coding for Unequal Costs?

Tags: language-agnostic, huffman-code

After much google searching for an algorithm to find the optimal prefix-free code for unequal letter costs, I still have found only PDFs and PS files that don't even have pseudocode for the algorithms they describe. Is there an implementation of any unequal-cost Huffman Coding algorithm available anywhere?

Comment: Why the close vote? If you tell me I can fix it...

Answer (score 1):

https://www.cs.umd.edu/~lijian/paper/Uneq_Let_Approx_conf_5.pdf

^ Contains pseudocode.  However, you really should understand the setting in which you apply this stuff, there are some subtleties.

Comment: Is there a reference implementation anywhere? That's what I'm asking. If not, then I suppose I'll just write it from the pseudocode, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: What's a "reference implementation" of an algorithm?   Who's officially in charge of an algorithm?

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is _any_ implementation of an unequal-cost-Huffman-Coding algorithm available in a common programming language. Do you know if such a thing exists?

Comment: Try some popular compression libraries.

Comment: @BadZen: Most compression libraries don't need unequal letter costs. In fact, I don't know of a famous compression algorithm which would need it. Since you mentioned compression libraries, can you please recommend such a library where it's likely to find unequal-cost-Huffman code?